# nesting elesif syntax

Tags: php, javascript, syntax, if-statement

I'm modifying a breadcrumb script to append a `'...'` if the title is over 40 characters long. I got that part worked out fine, but what I can't get right is how to nest it in this massive script to leave it along if it's under 40 characters long.

Do I even need an else here? I have never encountered a script where there were multiple `if`s without an `else` or `elseif`

```
    } elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
        if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . $after;
      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
        if ($showCurrent == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\s$delimiter\s$#", "$1", $cats);
        echo $cats;
        if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) > 40)) echo $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . '...' . $after;
      } elseif {
        if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) < 40)) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;

      }
```

Comment: This won't solve your actual problem, but something I use for this situation is on the server, I check if the length of the string is > 40 (like you do)...if so, add a class to the element called something like `"trimmed"` and only print the first 40 characters...then in your CSS, use this rule: `.trimmed:after { content: "..."; }`

Answer (score 0):

The last `elseif` is invalid, as it is already preceded by an else.

I would also say that you should get in the habit of using a standardized way of writing if / if-else statements.  It appears to me that your code is probably messed up because you have some if statements without curly braces and some with.  If you were to, for example, use curly braces in all cases, and use proper indentation for them, your problem of having and elseif following an else conditional would have been very clear to discover.

As an example:

```
if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
    $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
    echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
    if ($showCurrent == 1) {
         echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . $after;
    }
} else {
    $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
    $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
    if ($showCurrent == 0) {
        $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\s$delimiter\s$#", "$1", $cats);
    }
    echo $cats;
    if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) > 40)) {
        echo $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . '...' . $after;
    }
} else if {
    if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) < 40)) {
        echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
    }
}
```

To me, this is much clearer to read even though it is slightly more verbose. It is also readily clear that the last else-if makes no sense.

By the way, as you fix your logic, make sure you consider what happens if the string is exactly 40 characters long.

Comment: The code is not mine, i was just figuring out how to modify it to truncate insanely long post titles. I agree it's messy, but the script was long enough I decided not to spend the time on it now (this is just a small part). My code editor is flagging that last `else if`,  as a syntax error. When I remove it altogether it says it's fine. I don't fully understand why - if the editor is wrong or if I've missed something somewhere

Comment: @kristinachilds As I mentioned, this is not valid code.  you already have and `else` condition before it that would capture all cases where `get_post_type() != 'post'` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I would guess that the `if` that you have nested in the invalid `else-if` should actually be an `else-if` on the previous `if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) > 40)) {` statement.

Comment: I share your opinion, however the code works when I leave out the `else`s. When I add it, the script doesn't work. So I am baffled and wondering if this is correct. Here is the whole script in context: pastebin.com/TQ9kd30g

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be missing some curly brackets

```
} elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
      if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
        $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
        $slug = $post_type->rewrite;
        echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';

        if ($showCurrent == 1) { echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . $after; }

      } else {
        $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
        $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');

        if ($showCurrent == 0) { $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\s$delimiter\s$#", "$1", $cats);
        echo $cats; }

        if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) > 40)) { echo $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . '...' . $after; }

      } elseif {

        if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) < 40)) { echo $before . get_the_title() . $after; }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not clear.  You have not handled the case where the length is exactly 40 characters.

Try to structure your code so you only need to evaluate the same expression once.  Perhaps this is what you meant?

```
} elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
  if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
   ...
  } else {
    ...
    echo $cats;

    if (($showCurrent == 1) && (strlen($post->post_title) > 40)) 
      echo $before . substr(the_title('', '', FALSE), 0, 40) . '...' . $after;
    } 
    else {
      echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
    }
  }
}  // Close the elseif
```

Comment: I didn't think of that! Thank you. The `else` is still being flagged as a syntax error though. Perhaps the whole script needs to be seen in context? I was trying to save your eyes since this is just a small part (and the code is very ugly). http://pastebin.com/TQ9kd30g I highlighted it to help y'all out.

Comment: You need to close the enclosing `elseif` block.  I've added the brace above.

Comment: that causes even more problems because it throws off the other `elseif`s below it

Comment: Honestly, the braces look okay.  What is the specific syntax error?

Comment: It doesn't say, there's just a red alert box before every following `elseif`. Did you check out the pastebin code to see the whole thing in context? I wasn't sure if was apparent I posted it. It kinda blends in.

Comment: I'm not sure I would trust the syntax highlighting.  Try executing it.  If there is a syntax error it won't pass the PHP interpreter.

Comment: No dice. I'm truly stumped on this one. I tried appending `|| (strlen($post->post_title) = 40)` to it but that didn't work either.

Comment: Using `=` is an assignment, not a comparison (the PHP equality operator is `==`).